# How to update values of label on Focus out jquery event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update my `gridview` by calculating a few things like TotalPrice and TotalPriceGST. The calculation part works fine. I want to update the fields of TotalPrice and TotalPriceGST when i leave the UnitPriceTxt textbox (On Focus Out). But when i do it with the following code it updates the first row and doesn't allow me to write the price in the later textboxes. Please Help!

```
<div>
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_gvQuotationItems" style="color:#333333;width:900px;border-collapse:collapse;float: left">
        <tr style="color:White;background-color:#F07323;font-weight:bold;">
            <th scope="col">Product Code</th>
            <th scope="col">Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Sap Pack</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">UnitPrice</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Price with GST</th>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
            <td style="width:160px;">BCR123A-1EA</td>
            <td style="width:250px;">23477, Reference ethanols (H, M, L) (for</td>
            <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
            <td style="width:60px;">12</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="UnitPriceTxt" style="width:50px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:60px;"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;">
                <label id="TotalPriceGST"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:#284775;background-color:White;">
            <td style="width:160px;">459-UP</td>
            <td style="width:250px;">459 bubbler</td>
            <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
            <td style="width:60px;">123</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="UnitPriceTxt" style="width:50px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:60px;"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;">
                <label id="TotalPriceGST"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
            <td style="width:160px;">567-UP</td>
            <td style="width:250px;">567 Unprepared Customer Bubbler Purchase</td>
            <td style="width:30px;">1</td>
            <td style="width:60px;">50</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="UnitPriceTxt" style="width:50px;" />
            </td>
            <td style="width:60px;"></td>
            <td style="width:60px;">
                <label id="TotalPriceGST"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

This is My Script:

```
$(function () {
    $("#UnitPriceTxt").focusout(function () {
        var TextBoxtxt = $('#<%=gvQuotationItems.ClientID %>').find('input:text[id$="UnitPriceTxt"]').val();
        var TotalPriceLbl = $('#<%=gvQuotationItems.ClientID %>').find("#totalPrice");
        var TotalPriceGSTLbl = $('#<%=gvQuotationItems.ClientID %>').find("#TotalPriceGST");
        $("#<%=gvQuotationItems.ClientID %> tr").each(function () {
            if (!this.rowIndex) return;
            var Quantity = $(this).find("td:eq(3)").html();
            var UnitPrce = $(this).find('input:text[id$="UnitPriceTxt"]').val();
            var totalPrice = parseInt(Quantity) * parseInt(UnitPrce);
            var GST = (parseInt(Quantity) * 17) / 100;
            var TotalPriceGST;
            TotalPriceGST = totalPrice + GST;
            $(this).find("td:eq(5)").html('<label  id="totalPrice" style="font-size:small" >' + totalPrice + ".Rs" + '</label>');
            $(this).find("td:eq(6)").html('<label id="TotalPriceGST">' + TotalPriceGST + '</label>')
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: What ([MCVE]) HTML does that asp generate? Once it's in the browser the asp is - so far as I'm aware - irrelevant.

Comment: Please, so the grid view HTML, not the server side code. Don't make us imagine how it looks like.

Comment: @DavidThomas This asp generates a grid view with different columns I am taking the Quantity column and then i am calculation values for Total price and Total Price GST for each row. I want to do it with the focus out event. when the user leaves the textbox placed in one row .The gridview should update that particular row

Comment: Yes, I can imagine what it's producing, but it's so much better when we don't have to imagine; show us what the browser sees (the relevant HTML) and the answers are likely to be significantly better and more reliable.

Comment: @DavidThomas This is the only thing Inside the page! the Script and the grid view. The data inside the gridview  is bound with a datatable but that is not the concern here. I just want help on this line i want my labels to update when ever i lose focus on "UnitPriceTxt"
**bold**$("#UnitPriceTxt").focusout(function () {**bold**

Comment: @DavidThomas I have updated my question please Review it!

Comment: Much better like this. Inside your `$.each...` function, you create `label` with `id="TotalPriceGST"`. This creates multiple elements on your page with identical 'id' attribute, which in turn probably causes the bug you're describing. 'id' should be unique on the page.

Comment: @RonenCypis How can i make the ID unique Dynamically ? I am creating the label inside `$.each...` function because I am allowing the user to enter a price and then multiplying that price with the quantity he selected earlier!

Comment: @TalhaMalik, you can use the `i` inside your  `each` function like so: `$.each(function(i){...})`. The 'i' is the index of the current iteration of your `each` function. Just concatenate it to your static 'id' value...

Comment: @RonenCypis Can you please help me by suggestion any article about concatenating ID ?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `$('#UnitPriceTxt').blur(function(){...});`

`$.blur()` is the "focus out" function you're looking for.

Comment: It doesn't do anything with the .Blur event. With the .Focusout event it atleast updates a single row of the gridview!